# Find Rotation Angle between two points on Circle

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find the rotation angle between two points on a circle in clockwise sense.

I have the formula for rotating a point around a circle:

$$x'=x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta\\y'=-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta$$

Otherwise stated by the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\
y'
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}$$

I am simply trying to reverse these two functions and solve for $\theta$.

Yea, I'm a little rusty when it comes to "reversing equations" or solving for something in it, and I've been struggling with this for two weeks. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan \theta=m=\frac yx,\tan\theta'=m'=\frac {y'}{x'},\tan(\theta'-\theta)=\frac{m'-m}{1+mm'}=\frac{y'/x'-y/x}{1+yy'/xx'}$$
So:
$$\Delta\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{xy'-yx'}{xx'+yy'}\right)$$

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thank you!